# Вывести список в 2 колонки

Tags: css3, css

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

есть список в блоке определённой высоты. высота списка больше высоты блока, поэтому он [отображается в 2 колонки](http://jsfiddle.net/7tT2G/)

у меня не получается сделать так чтобы сначала заполнялась пунктами списка первая колонка, затем вторая. [выглядит это так](http://prozaik.16mb.com/html5_2/lists/lists.png)

Answer (score 16):

Обновление

http://jsfiddle.net/4E9sB/

```css
.wrap ol {
  list-style-position: inside;
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-count: 2;
  list-style-type: decimal;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ol>
    <li><span>Real time analitics dashme analitics daboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real  dashboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real time analitics dashboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real time ard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real time analitics dame analitics dame analitics dashboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real titics dashboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real time analitics dashboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real time anahboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real time analitics dme analitics dame analitics daashboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real time analitics dashboard</span></li>
    <li><span>Real time anahboard</span></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант решения. но на картинке немного другое - сначала заполняется первый столбец до полной высоты блока-родителя

Comment: Так оно так и есть пробовали менять?
http://jsfiddle.net/4E9sB/

Обновил.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, сначала должна заполняться левая колонка, на всю высоту блока, и только если не влезло -- правая. Смотрите картинку, приложенную к вопросу.

Comment: Вы смеетесь? А как в моем примере, по другому?

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, увеличил высоту в несколько раз -- действительно работает, прошу простить. Текст крупный, при увеличении на 100-200 пикселей разницы не видно.

Comment: А можно добавить в пример выпадающее под меню?